# Reflection - private method

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection

In my test I have:

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    savedStateHandle = SavedStateHandle()
    saveImageUseCase = Mockito.mock(SaveImageUseCase::class.java)
    repo = FakeRepository()
    viewModel = AreaEditViewModel(repo, savedStateHandle, saveImageUseCase)
    }

@Test
fun setUpArea() = runTest {
    val method = viewModel.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("setUpArea", Long::class.java)
    method.isAccessible = true
    method.invoke(viewModel, 2L)

...
    }
```

in my viewModel:

```
private suspend fun setUpArea(areaId: Long) {
    repository.getAreaById(areaId).first() {
        savedStateHandle["area"] = it
        true
    }
}
```

when I run my test I get:
com.rachapps.area_feature.viewModel.AreaEditViewModel.setUpArea(long)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.rachapps.area_feature.viewModel.AreaEditViewModel.setUpArea(long)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2707)
at com.rachapps.area_feature.viewModel.AreaEditViewModelTest$setUpArea$1.invokeSuspend(AreaEditViewModelTest.kt:61)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of "suspended"
I need to use Kotlin's reflection